# after_request in flask is run after the request is done but terminal shows otherwise

Tags: python, flask

Code:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "<h2> Hello, world </h2>"

@app.after_request
def after(response)
    print('after request')
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Terminal Output:

```
 Serving Flask app "test" (lazy loading)
 Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 Debug mode: on
 Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 Restarting with stat
 Debugger is active!
after request
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Aug/2020 14:31:07] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

I am learning Flask and am totally new to web programming. My question is shouldn't 'after request' be printed after the GET request. Can you point out where I am going wrong ? How should I interpret the result ?

Comment: add a `print()` to the `index()` code and see if its running first

Comment: Don't trust the order that the log gets printed to the terminal. I've been bitten by this before